# Sum decimal numbers in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, gis, google-earth-engine

I need to sum values from different arrays, but the problem is that an array that contains the number 0.5 is recognized just as 0. . I need to sum the decimal part of the number (.5) because is to calculate an index.

This is my code

```
red_band = dataset.read(4)
nir_band = dataset.read(5)
L = np.full_like(red_band, 0.5)


savi = ((nir_band.astype(float) - red_band.astype(float)) / (red_band.astype(float) + nir_band.astype(float) + L))*(np.full_like(red_band, 1) + L)
```

And this is an example of my ouput for variable L

```
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.full_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full_like.html) matches the size *and type* of the given array. In this case, `red_band` is a integer array (specifically `uint16`). Attempting to populate an integer array with a floating point number like `0.5` results in truncation, hence why `L` contains all `0`s.

To create a float array with the same size as `red_band`, you can use [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) instead:

```
L = np.full(red_band.shape, 0.5)
```

Comment: It worked as I need with .shape instead of .size. Thank you!